# How should i measure execution time of a C++ program when I execute it from Java code?

Tags: java, c++

I understand the question may not make sense at first, but I'll explain it here.

First, I have the following **C++** code, a simple Hello World.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  printf("Hello World ");
  return(0);
}
```

Now I am calling it from within **Java** using this:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/name/./test");  
long totalTime = System.nanoTime() - start;

System.out.println("Time: " + totalTime);
```

After doing this a couple times i get the following output:

Time: 8155128

Time: 732204

Time: 508819

Time: 662987

I wonder if this is a correct way to measure the time for the c++ code execution and i am want to know if there is an explanation on why always the first execution shows a time 10X bigger than the others (even if it's nanoseconds)

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate. It certainly is not the JIT which is causing the program to run so much faster the second time, given it's a JNI program.

Comment: Pretend you're a professional and profile the code.

Answer (score 2):

The operating system probably put the c++ application in cache so it would be faster to execute the next time around.

Comment: 8 ms is about the time for one or two non-SSD hard-drive seeks (the read time is negligible). Since `libc` is probably already in the RAM allocated for the disk cache, that means either just the executable or the executable and one library specific to it.